# How to remove span tag generated by checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Checkbox is randomly generating span tag.
Current Code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_select"  type="checkbox" ClienIDMode="Static" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);" />


<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="CheckBox_select" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ID="cbs" />
```

Generated:

```
<span type="checkbox"><input id="CheckBox_select" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl02$CheckBox_select" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);"></span>
```

How to remove the Span tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#CheckBox_select').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span type="checkbox"><input id="CheckBox_select" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl02$CheckBox_select" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);"></span>
```

use [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

> Description: Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

Comment: @LeonardWongleothelion96 glad to help mate happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.unwrap()` to remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.:

```js
var pTags = $( "#CheckBox_select" );
if ( pTags.parent().is( "span" ) ) 
    pTags.unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span type="checkbox"><input id="CheckBox_select" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl02$CheckBox_select" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Literally spent hours solving it